# ADO.NET Entity Framework Compiled Queries with ObjectSet Only

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I cannot find an example of using a compiled query with the objectset intead of the ObjectContext instance... so is it possible to create a compiled query with only the ObjectSet?  This will fit in better with my architecture.

Thanks.

Comment: ObjectSet has a Context property. You may have to use that. One of the args to `Compile( , )` must be a Context from what I can tell.

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to, but my architecture would have worked really well with the ObjectSet... oh well.  Thanks.

Comment: http://linqautocompiler.codeplex.com/ might work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of the most simple `Compile` version looks like:

```
public static Func<TContext, TResult> Compile<TContext, TResult>(Expression<Func<TContext, TResult>> query)   
    where TContext : ObjectContext
{
    return new Func<TContext, TResult>(new CompiledQuery(query).Invoke<TContext, TResult>);
}
```

Invoking compiled query requires `ObjectContext`, there is no version accepting `ObjectSet`.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectSet has a Context property. You would have to use that. One of the args to `Compile( , )` must be a Context from what I can tell (as confirmed by @Ladislav.